# Why luma parameter differs in opencv and matlab?

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, image-processing, numpy

I'm using this code to extract luma from an image in matlab:

```
I = imread('myphoto.bmp');
I = rgb2ycbcr(I);
I = I[:, :, 1];
imwrite(I, 'luma.bmp');
```

And this one to do the same in opencv-python:

```
I = cv2.imread('myphoto.bmp')
I = cv2.cvtColor(I, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB)
I = I[:, :, 0]
cv2.imwrite('luma.bmp', I)
```

But I obtain quite different results!

Here's the obtained images:

Matlab:
[image: MATLAB]

OpenCV:
[image: OpenCV]

Is there a reason behind this? How can I obtain more similar results?

Comment: The reason of the difference is explained in the official docs for rgb2ycbcr and cvtColor, that you have carefully read, haven't you? At any rate... you can apply a linear transformation to the luma values like in L = 16+(219*L)/255.

Comment: MATLAB also gamma corrects the images where OpenCV doesn't.  I found this out by accident when I was taking a look at the distribution of pixels between the same image loaded in both frameworks.  Try normalizing each to `[0,255]` to be consistent, like what gboffi suggested.

Comment: @rayryeng Uhm, I didn't noticed such a problem with this image when I load it as a bmp file. Although when I use a jpeg I get very different results.

Comment: @gboffi you can post you comment as an answer...

Comment: note that [`cv::imread`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imread) will convert the image to 8-bit integer type by default. If you want to load the image as is, set the `flag` option to `-1`.