# How to get the same output of rgb2ycbcr() matlab function in python-opencv?

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, numpy, matrix

I'm using this code to extract luma from an image in matlab:

```
I = imread('image.bmp');
I = rgb2ycbcr(I);
I = I[:, :, 1];
save(I, 'ycbcr_image');
```

Here is the image:
[image: Image to convert to ycbcr]
And here is the [output mat](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ahb49yvsuyh0dzj/ycbcr.mat?dl=0).
I'd like to replicate this code in opencv-python, here is my implementation:

```
def to_matlab_ycbcr(image):
  # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26078281/why-luma-parameter-differs-in-opencv-and-matlab
  return clip(16 + (219 / 255.0) * image, 0, 255)

original = image_open(local_path('image.bmp'))
matlab = scipy.io.loadmat(local_path('ycbcr.mat'))
matlab = matlab['ycbcr_image']
transformed = cv2.cvtColor(original, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB)
transformed = transformed[:, :, 0]
result = to_matlab_ycbcr(transformed)
error = np.mean(np.abs(result - matlab))
```

My error is on average 12. Do you know how to fix this?

P.s. I'm using **python 2.7.5** and **opencv 2.4.9**

Comment: Conversion matrices between color spaces might differ in matlab and isn't it?

Comment: Here's one possible reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15561915/why-is-the-y-converted-by-rgb2ycbcr-in-the-matlab-in-the-range-16-235

Answer (score 1):

Using this code

```
def rgb2ycbcr(im_rgb):
 im_rgb = im_rgb.astype(np.float32)
 im_ycrcb = cv2.cvtColor(im_rgb, cv2.COLOR_RGB2YCR_CB)
 im_ycbcr = im_ycrcb[:,:,(0,2,1)].astype(np.float32)
 im_ycbcr[:,:,0] = (im_ycbcr[:,:,0]*(235-16)+16)/255.0 #to [16/255, 235/255]
 im_ycbcr[:,:,1:] = (im_ycbcr[:,:,1:]*(240-16)+16)/255.0 #to [16/255, 240/255]
 return im_ycbcr
```

and maybe you will want this code

```
def ycbcr2rgb(im_ycbcr):
 im_ycbcr = im_ycbcr.astype(np.float32)
 im_ycbcr[:,:,0] = (im_ycbcr[:,:,0]*255.0-16)/(235-16) #to [0, 1]
 im_ycbcr[:,:,1:] = (im_ycbcr[:,:,1:]*255.0-16)/(240-16) #to [0, 1]
 im_ycrcb = im_ycbcr[:,:,(0,2,1)].astype(np.float32)
 im_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(im_ycrcb, cv2.COLOR_YCR_CB2RGB)
 return im_rgb
```

Comment: Reminder: OpenCV defaults to BGR not RGB but this code takes RGB (but does not give very noticeable error at first glance when you give it BGR!). I know this is like OpenCV 101, but stupid me spent two hours before figuring this out.